# How to check two different webforms having same value of textboxes

Tags: asp.net, validation, jquery-validate, webforms

aspx
TextBox1.Text
World.aspx
TextBox1.Text

I want the pages Hello.aspx and World.aspx having same value of validation

please help me anybody have the idea about this

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the value on the first page using cookies or database or something else.
Then retrieve the value in the second page and compare the values in the validation function or event.

```
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {


    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;

        string sql = string.Format(@"select email from customers where customer_id = '{0}'", customer_id);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //try and catch block would go here

        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string email = rdr[0].ToString();
        cn.Close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you give me an example in sql database

Comment: i know how to store the value but i want to retrieve it please give an example to my full question.

Comment: Sorry I can help but I can't do it for you.

Comment: sorry sir please help me to resolve it its main important my project

Comment: Please Georges sir help me to resolve dont miss understand me

Comment: You have all you need in the different link and answer I gave. http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/Save-and-Retrieve-Files-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx and http://forums.asp.net/t/1857135.aspx/1?Retrieve+data+from+Data+base+using+asp+net+2010